# Query excel sheet in c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I want to read Excel file in c# using following code

```
string excelFileName = "Book2.xls";
string excelConnectString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Book2.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
//string excelConnectString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + excelFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties = Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";

OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectString);
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Sheet1$]", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objDatAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objDatAdap.SelectCommand = objCmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
objDatAdap.Fill(ds);
```

[image]

Everything is working fine.Now my requirement is to read the excel file something like below

```
SELECT A,B,D From [Sheet1];
```

Comment: You want to search using Column names?

Comment: @Anuraj:No by cell like 'select A,B,C from sheet'

Comment: i think you can't do that... a little workaround is to make a "Select *" fill the dataset and after remove the columns from the dataset...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Select-command should look like this if you want to read A1 to D1:

```
SELECT * FROM [SHEETNAME_HERE$A1:D1]
```

Whole Code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
    "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source="
    + XLS_FILE_NAME_AND_PATH_HERE
    + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
stbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM [" + SHEETNAME_HERE + "$A1:D1]");
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(stbQuery.ToString(), con);

DataSet dsXLS = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(dsXLS);

DataView dvEmp = new DataView(dsXLS.Tables[0]);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dvEmp;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DataTable Contents = new DataTable();
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", objConn))
{
    adapter.Fill(Contents);
}
Console.WriteLine(Contents.Rows[0][0]);
```

You can select a particular cell by passing the proper index.

Answer (score 2):

You can just constuct use query like that:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Mobile FROM [Sheet1$]
```

i.e. use first row values as column names.