# Read Nth row as columns using OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I am trying to import an xlsx file data into a DataTable. I want to read the 2nd row as columns row or maybe 4th row as columns. currently I am using the below code which is working fine, wanted to know is there any other way to read the excel data from 2nd/4th rows?

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromSecondRow(string filePath,string sheetName)
    {
        var oleDbConnection = new ExcelToDb(filePath).GetOleDbConnection();
        using (OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("select * from [{0}${1}]", sheetName, "A2:end"), oleDbConnection))
        {
            oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue with the code is when I am trying to read the excel file to the end by using "A2:end" it is leaving the data after few blank rows which is not a correct way.
can we use something like "dt1.AsEnumerable.Skip(3)" which skips not just the rows but also the first row default column?

Example picture - would like to read my data as second table by skipping first 2-3 lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `NPOI` to read excel, it can easily use rowNumber and colNumber to get cell value, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5856025/4573839):

```
sheet.GetRow(rowNumber).GetCell(colNumber).StringCellValue))
```

NPOI can [add by Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/).

update:

`Select * From [SheetName$]` may work, it can select all data on sheet including middle empty cell, then it can use `datatable.Rows[rowNum][colNum]` to get any cell value, [reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6790298/4573839).

Comment: No as I’m developing a project using internal tools in my company I’m not allowed to use others packages. That was the reason i mentioned OLEDB specifically

Comment: i update my answer